# Return rank by ID

Tags: r

Over a list of data frame containing two columns Year and Value. I've sorted values ​​in ascending order, by Year. Now I would like to return the position of each value in his yearly series to plot them and compare these ranked yearly series among dataframes.

Here is an example of the dataset

```
#data
df1 <- data.frame(Year = c(1860, 1860, 1860, 1861, 1861, 1862, 1862, 1862), Value = c(487, 456, 123, 159, 123, 789, 456, 321)) 
df2 <- data.frame(Year = c(1916, 1916, 1917, 1917, 1917, 1918, 1918, 1918, 1919, 1919), Value = c(123, 456, 487, 123, 159, 321, 789, 456, 487, 154)) 
l <- list(df1, df2)
```

Step1 : I've ordered values by Year using a simple `order()` in `lapply` function

```
sort.df <- lapply(l, function(x) {
x[order(x$"Year", x$"Value"), ]
})
```

Step2 : I was thinking to `cbind()`a sequence of number values by year using a loop with

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
require (dplyr)
require (purr)
df %>% group_by(df$"Year") %>%
seq(1, (as.numeric(nrow(df[which(df$Year == i), ]))), 1)
}
```

I'm simply not able to integrate this into a `lapply()` function ... But it works for a given year of a given df.

Is there a way to do this ?

```
#result
df1.1 <- data.frame(Year = c(1860, 1860, 1860, 1861, 1861, 1862, 1862, 1862), Value = c(123, 456, 487, 123, 159, 321, 456, 789), Rank = c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3)) 
df2.1 <- data.frame(Year = c(1916, 1916, 1917, 1917, 1917, 1918, 1918, 1918, 1919, 1919), Value = c(123, 456, 123, 159, 487, 321, 456, 789, 154, 487), Rank = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2)) 
l.1 <- list(df1.1, df2.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be:

```
library(tidyverse)

 l %>% 
   map(. %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   mutate(Rank = rank(Value)))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Year [3]
   Year Value  Rank
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1860   487     3
2  1860   456     2
3  1860   123     1
4  1861   159     2
5  1861   123     1
6  1862   789     3
7  1862   456     2
8  1862   321     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   Year [4]
    Year Value  Rank
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1916   123     1
 2  1916   456     2
 3  1917   487     3
 4  1917   123     1
 5  1917   159     2
 6  1918   321     1
 7  1918   789     3
 8  1918   456     2
 9  1919   487     2
10  1919   154     1
```